# How can I add aliases to an array of numbers in typescript

Tags: typescript, styled-system

I'm trying to add some aliases to an array of numbers but typescript wont accept it, here is the code:

```
  interface FontSizeAliases {
  micro: number
  small: number
  default: number
  large: number
}


const fontSizes: number[] & FontSizeAliases = [12, 14, 16, 18, 22, 30, 40]
fontSizes.micro = fontSizes[0]
fontSizes.small = fontSizes[1]
fontSizes.default = fontSizes[2]
fontSizes.large = fontSizes[3]
```

compiler error:

```
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[] & FontSizeAliases'.
  Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type 'FontSizeAliases': micro, small, default, large
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your array doesn't have `micro` etc. when you assign it to the `fontSizes` constant, but that constant's type requires it.

`Object.assign` is often used to build up things like that (but keep reading, I work up to a third option which I think is probably best):

```typescript
interface FontSizeAliases {
    micro: number;
    small: number;
    default: number;
    large: number;
}

const rawSizes = [12, 14, 16, 18, 22, 30, 40];
const fontSizes: number[] & FontSizeAliases = Object.assign(rawSizes, {
    micro: rawSizes[0],
    small: rawSizes[1],
    default: rawSizes[2],
    large: rawSizes[3],
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHtwGVgC8ICCANsHAM4RnIDeAUMg8gLbAJToBcyIArkwEbQA3PUZkmcIkS68Bw0QwAmEeDyJgZfQVBGNkROFADmETXJ20AvrVoJMZMMihwA7jnxUAvMgDaARgAmABpkPwAWEL8ANkiADhCA4OQAZgAGELDUgF0ROxAHZBhMMHdKM20fLOQAMjRi0uJSCi9kAHl+ACsIBDAAOnIyYCMQAApnNzxKELo9FjZOJ1dSsh9soIVkcUlpRYmPfyz1vWVVdS5x5Z8Aw42DY1Ndy+SbywBKESA)

Another option is to build them up in a `Partial<FontSizeAliases>`:

```typescript
interface FontSizeAliases {
    micro: number;
    small: number;
    default: number;
    large: number;
}

const rawSizes: number[] & Partial<FontSizeAliases> = [12, 14, 16, 18, 22, 30, 40];
rawSizes.micro = rawSizes[0];
rawSizes.small = rawSizes[1];
rawSizes.default = rawSizes[2];
rawSizes.large = rawSizes[3];
const fontSizes = rawSizes as number[] & FontSizeAliases;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHtwGVgC8ICCANsHAM4RnIDeAUMg8gLbAJToBcyIArkwEbQA3PUZkmcIkS68Bw0QwAmEeDyJgZfQVBGNkROFADmETXJ20AvrVoJMZMMihwA7jnxkz2gNoBdZABkyAAKhmCkRAA8GNh4hCTklAB8yAC8yN4AjABMADTImQAs+ZkAbCUAHPnZecgAzAAM+YUNviLObnFkAHQsbOhpTq7ulN6t7cNd3eKSRIMdI2RZbbQLU8qq6vOTHt7ZK2se3QbGKOmHo3UrdiAOyDCYYIvbnR7I5Nxa0H6BaI8jxFIFDIIiAA)

In both of those, though, you have the issue that you could miss out one of the sizes (`small`, for instance). To fix *that*, you can create the sizes separately with full typechecking, then combine them:

```typescript
interface FontSizeAliases {
    micro: number;
    small: number;
    default: number;
    large: number;
}

const rawSizes = [12, 14, 16, 18, 22, 30, 40];
const sizeNames: FontSizeAliases = {
    micro: rawSizes[0],
    small: rawSizes[1],
    default: rawSizes[2],
    large: rawSizes[3],
};
const fontSizes = Object.assign([], rawSizes, sizeNames);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHtwGVgC8ICCANsHAM4RnIDeAUMg8gLbAJToBcyIArkwEbQA3PUZkmcIkS68Bw0QwAmEeDyJgZfQVBGNkROFADmETXJ20AvrVoJMZMMihwA7jnxUAvMgDaARgAmABpkPwAWEL8ANkiADhCA4OQAZgAGELDUgF0ROxAHZDI8CAA5OCZKLgxsYuJSCi8aBWZWdi5nN2KyH2yg5vFJaSdXd0p-LL69ZVV1dpGunwCJ5oNjU2HOjx9k5ctc%200cYTDBRxoB5fgArCAQwADpyIqMQAAofCY3TkKL8MoqyACUQiAA)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to slightly modify your types, like this:

```
interface FontSizeAliases {
    micro?: number
    small?: number
    default?: number
    large?: number
}

const fontSizes: number[] & FontSizeAliases = [12, 14, 16, 18, 22, 30, 40]

fontSizes.micro = fontSizes[0]
fontSizes.small = fontSizes[1]
fontSizes.default = fontSizes[2]
fontSizes.large = fontSizes[3]
```

I've made micro optional, this will give you intellisense and make sure you will not forget to check undefined

[Link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHtwGVgC8ICCANsHAM4RnIDeAsAFDJPIC2wCU6A-AFzIgBXFgCNoDZsjIs4RIr35DRUccwAmEeAKJh5gkWMbMicKAHMIuxQYC%20DO-QSYyYZDExgc%20Mnz1KA2gC6yABkaO6ehCTklMgAvMh%20AIwATAA0yIkALOmJAGw5ABzpyWnIAMwADOmZFQH2bth4lAB0bBzoca7hTWR%20tQwNHj3NUjJEnYMRvYl19JPD6praE91efsmz817NxmYo8VuUfmUBQA)

Comment: The problem here is that they'll continue to be optional everywhere they're used.

Comment: Yep. I than we need to clarify with OP the possibility of having unfilled object. In case this is not the case - your answer way better. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I agree with @T.J.Crowder. Thank you Drag13

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to reduce boilerplate by making a utility function. It does have a `@ts-ignore`, but you can reuse it without errors.

This version lets you specify every index manually:

```
const keyedArray = <T, U extends string>(
  values: T[],
  names: { [k in U]: number }
): T[] & { [k in U]: T } => {
  // @ts-ignore
  return Object.assign(
    [...values],
    Object.entries<number>(names).reduce(
      (acc, [name, index]) => ({
        ...acc,
        [name]: values[index],
      }),
      {}
    )
  );
};

const fontSizes = keyedArray([0, 2, 16], { sm: 0, lg: 1, xl: 2 });
/*
const fontSizes: number[] & {
    sm: number;
    lg: number;
    xl: number;
}
*/
```